# How i can make where inside a relationship in adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have this query:

```
const filter = request.input('filter')
const queryBookQuestions =  BookUnitQuestion
                                    .query()
                                    .with('book_unit')
                                    .with('user')
                                    .with('book', (builder) => {
                                        builder.where('id', request.params.id)
                                    })
```

In this query i return all book unit questions with the object book_unit related, the user and the book that i receive with params (request.params.id).

Now i need to filter the unit. I actually have this filter that make a where in the "description":

```
if(filter){
            if(filter.search("description") !== -1){
                let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                queryBookQuestions.where('description', 'ilike', '%'+description[0]+'%')
            }
```

This filter works well but he is applying directly in the BookUnitQuestion Model. But now, i need to make a filter that filter by unit, something like:

```
if(filter.search("unit") !== -1){
                let unit = request.input('filter').match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)

                queryBookQuestions.where('book_unit.unit', unit[0])}

        }
```

But this don't work because the book_unit is an array of object inside the book_unit_question.
when i try to filter this way i receive:

> select count(*) as "total" from "book_unit_question" where
>   "book_unit"."unit" = $1 - missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "book_unit"

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, after with('book_unit') you can do:

```
filter = request.input('filter')
const queryBookQuestions =  BookUnitQuestion
    .query()
    .with('book_unit')
    .whereHas('book_unit', (builder) => {
        ...your filter here
    })
    .with('user')
    .with('book', (builder) => {
        builder.where('id', request.params.id)
    })
```